# Convert dd/mm/yyyy HH:MM to POSIXct class

Tags: r

I'm having a problem using `sub` function in R, I have to create a POSIXct vector from a character one and I decided to fit it on ISO standard before reading it whith `as.POSIXct`.

the strings I have look like this:

```
"01/01/2015 08:00"
```

the strings I want look like this:

```
"2015-01-01 08:00"
```

this is the code I used:

```
s= gsub('^([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{4})', '\3-\2-\1', s)
```

the results I have look like this:

```
"\003-\002-\001 08:00"
```

of course I can simply use the parameters of `as.POSIXct` to read the vector as it is, but how is it possible thath I get such a result? I can't make sense of this.

Comment: you need to double escape in the replacement part : `gsub('^([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{4})', '\\3-\\2-\\1', s)` - but apart from this "typo" correction, I agree that in your case it is better to work with `as.POSIXct`

Comment: To use the parameters of `as.POSIXct` is much cleaner than fiddling with regular expressions, IMHO.

Comment: it is indeed, but I'm quite used to regex so my first approach was to use them, and I didn't like thath I couldn't use them on R. my question was actually all about string replacement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `lubridate` to convert to DateTime class

```
library(lubridate)
dmy_hm(str1)
#[1] "2015-01-01 08:00:00 UTC"
```

Or this can be done with `as.POSIXct` as @DavidArenburg commented

```
 as.POSIXct(str1, format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
```

if it needs to be of specific `format`, use the `format`

```
format(dmy_hm(str1), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
#[1] "2015-01-01 08:00"
```

If we want a regex way (but it is not recommended to use regex on Date Time), we can capture the characters as a group (first two characters in the 1st capture group, followed by one character, next two characters in 2nd capture group, leaving the next character, and the last four characters in third capture group.  In the replacement, we can change the backreference order to get the expected output

```
sub("(.{2}).(.{2}).(.{4})", "\\3-\\2-\\1", str1)
#[1] "2015-01-01 08:00"
```

#### data

```
str1 <- "01/01/2015 08:00"
```

Comment: OP says "*I have to create a POSIXct vector*" so why not just `as.POSIXct(str1, format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")`?

Comment: double backslash worked fine. thanks

Comment: As @DavidArenburg said, why use an external library, when `as.POSIXct` does exactly what is needed?

Comment: @Rodrigo  I think I read the question incorrectly as I thought the OP wanted to specifically use regex and also want t in some format

Answer (score 2):

Never ever use regular expression on dates. We have proper types for that, and for a reason.

I like the [anytime](https://cran.r-project.org/package=anytime) package this (and wrote it) as it converts (sane) input *without requiring a format string*:

```
R> library(anytime)
R> anytime("01/01/2015 08:00")
[1] "2015-01-01 08:00:00 CST"
R>
```

It also has a few helpful format helpers if you don't want to do it by hand.  But as David Arenburg noted, all this *can be done with base R*:

```
R>rfc2822( anytime("01/01/2015 08:00") )
[1] "Thu, 01 Jan 2015 08:00:00.000000 -0600"
R> rfc3339( anytime("01/01/2015 08:00") )
[1] "2015-01-01T08:00:00.000000-0600"
R> iso8601( anytime("01/01/2015 08:00") )
[1] "2015-01-01 08:00:00"
R>
```