# How to convert format of time R?

Tags: r, datetime

I have a dataframe with the time in the following format:

```
Time
01.01.2017 01:00
01.01.2017 02:00
01.01.2017 03:00
01.01.2017 04:00 
01.01.2017 05:00 
01.01.2017 06:00

class(df$Time) 
[1] "factor"
```

Its day, month, year, hours, minutes. I want to convert it into a readable time. I tried this already:

```
strptime(df$Time, format="%d-%m-%Y  %H:%M")
as.POSIXct(df$Time)
```

It doesnt work. How can I transform it and change the format to: 2017-01-01 01:00. So I want to have Year, month, day, hours, minutes.

Comment: The format you give in `strptime` should follow the format your date is in. Your dates are separated with `.`, not `-`.  Basically a typo

Comment: @camille do you think it is not a dupe

Comment: @akrun typing `-` instead of `.` is a typo. Beyond that, yes, there are many posts on formatting dates. If you have a good dupe candidate, you can flag it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Read `?strptime` you need the `format` to be

```
strptime("01.01.2017 01:00", format="%d.%m.%Y  %H:%M")
#[1] "2017-01-01 01:00:00"
```

If you need output to be in the particular format we can use `format`

```
format(strptime("01.01.2017 01:00", format="%d.%m.%Y  %H:%M"), "%Y-%m-%d  %H:%M")
#[1] "2017-01-01  01:00"
```

Same would work with `as.POSIXct`

```
as.POSIXct("01.01.2017 01:00", format="%d.%m.%Y  %H:%M")
```

Or to ignore specifying formats directly use `lubridate::dmy_hm`

```
lubridate::dmy_hm("01.01.2017 01:00")
```

One thing to note as mentioned by @42- is although they look the same the output of `format` is a character value whereas that of `as.POSIXct` and `strptime` is a datetime value.

Comment: Thank you! I see, I have made a small mistake! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Ronak. Your answer would be improved by emphasizing that the result from format.POSIXt is a character value rather than a datetime value despite the fact that they appear the same at the console level.

Comment: @42- thanks. I have updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

We can just use `anytime`

```
librrary(anytime)
anytime(df$Time)
#[1] "2017-01-01 01:00:00 EST" "2017-01-01 02:00:00 EST" "2017-01-01 03:00:00 EST" "2017-01-01 04:00:00 EST"
#[5] "2017-01-01 05:00:00 EST" "2017-01-01 06:00:00 EST"
```

NOTE: There are a multiple dupes for this post

Possible dupes of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49109665/how-do-i-convert-dd-mm-yyyy-hhmmss-to-dd-mm-yy-hhmm-in-r) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42371045/convert-dd-mm-yyyy-hhmm-to-posixct-class) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13642175/convert-string-of-anyformat-into-dd-mm-yy-hhmmss-in-r)

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Time = c("01.01.2017 01:00", "01.01.2017 02:00", 
 "01.01.2017 03:00", "01.01.2017 04:00", "01.01.2017 05:00", 
 "01.01.2017 06:00"
 )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```